# Dart remove all brackets with integers between them

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

In `Dart` language how can i remove all brackets which i have integers between them, for example in this below string i want to remove `[1]` and `[100]`. integers of between brackets aren't specific

with this code i can remove all brackets but i can't remove all integers

```dart
String s = "Hello, world![1] i am 'foo' [100]";
print(s.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'(?:_|[^\w\s])+'),''));
```

output:

```
Hello, world!1 i am 'foo' 100
```

that should be:

```
Hello, world! i am 'foo'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
String s = "Hello, world![1] i am 'foo' [100]";
print(s.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\s*\[\d+]'),''));
// => Hello, world! i am 'foo'
```

The `\s*\[\d+]` regex matches

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jvhrUk/1).

Answer (score -2):

you can try this

```
print(s.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'([^\D])+'),'').replaceAll("[]",''));
```

**Output** - Hello, world! i am 'foo'